# smbus/I2C sensor returns fixed data

Tags: python, sensor, i2c

### I am attempting to use a sensor in conjunction with a raspberry pi smbus. When I try and read a specific byte of data, it returns 181. No matter what byte you tell it to read it returns 181, regardless of whether that byte actually exists or not.

Equipment: raspberry PI zero w connecting to a MikroeElictronika air quality 2 click via SMBus and I2C. Connected via a 2 click board. Other slot has a Adafruit ultimate GPS sensor that works fine.

https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/iaq-core-datasheet-en-v1.pdf

## Code:

```
import smbus 
from time import sleep


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

def read_byte(byte):

    reading = bus.read_byte_data(0x5a,byte)

    return reading


co2 = read_byte(0x01)

print(co2)

sleep(5)

status = read_byte(0x2)

print(status)

bus.close()
```

this does not return any error but even if the sensor is stimulated it returns 181. 
none of the error messages output by the device are 181.

If you do not specify a byte, it does return a value that corresponds to air quality, but not one that corresponds with any of the outputs the sensor is meant to have. This is not the main problem but I have included it in case it helps.

### Code:

```
reading = bus.read_byte(add)
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Please help as I have little experience in this area. This is a school project.

UPDATE:
I have got I2C to block read the data

pigs reading returns:

9 1 199 0 0 1 249 51 0 127

I2C block read returns:

[181, 127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]

my pigpio python returns  (-25L, ' ' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think a little about how the I2C bus works.

There may be many devices on the bus.  They know if they are being addressed by checking to see if their address is placed on the bus.  To distinguish their address from random bus data the address is only checked at the start of an I2C transaction.

The start of an I2C transaction is signaled by a start condition, the selected device address is then placed on the bus (with the read/write bit).  The (selected) device stays selected until a stop condition is signaled.

Each SMBus command is bracketed by a start and stop condition.  Your device, like many I2C devices, seems to reset its internal state when a start condition is seen.

The end result means you are always reading the same byte from the device.  I.e. byte 0 (the first byte) of the 16 bit pred value.

Use a command which reads all the 9 bytes in one transaction, perhaps the SMBus I2C block read instruction.

---

In pigpio Python

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit()

h = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x5a)

c, d = pi.i2c_read_device(h, 9)

print(d)

pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()
```

---

From the command line with pigs

```
sudo pigpiod # if not already running
...
pigs i2co 1 0x5A 0 # returns a handle, 0 for first open
...
pigs i2crd 0 9 # assuming 0 is handle returned by open
...
pigs i2cc 0 # close when finished, assuming 0 is handle returned by open
```

Comment: if you mean physical devices there is only one other device and it does not use I2C

Comment: so you mean reading = bus.read_block_data(0x00, 0x09,byte)

Comment: ok that does return data that changes when I blow on the sensor but how do I make the code work?

Comment: Although the data does not really make sense. Resistance changes but the Co2 reading doesn't. Byte 2 is 194, witch makes no sense as that isn't one of the possible values.

Comment: ok I did not know that so I was reading the data wrong

Comment: are you one of the developers/makers/important ppl for pigpio?

Comment: Respect to you. How do I make the block read work with pigpio? I have got pi = pigio.pi() to work but I cant figure out the inputs for the block read command

Comment: I have tried the SMBus and it returns [181, 127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255] witch cannot be the data

Comment: can you explain to me what a handle is and how to define one? the website really isn't clear on what it is. Also do you mean i2c_read_device(handle, 9)?

Comment: ok thanks I will post an update once I have tried that

Comment: when I put in 9 it has a huge error

Comment: NoneType object has no attribute send it triggers when I try and close it

Comment: I tried closing i2c with i2c_close but that hasn't helped

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73204/discussion-on-answer-by-joan-smbus-i2c-sensor-returns-fixed-data).

Comment: still not working and I copied your exact code

Comment: You need to say what happens?  Have I made a typo, does it run, does it give an error, does it print a result?

Comment: I did in the chat

Comment: it is an error that occurs when the program tries to run pi.close() error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: except occasionally it just works

Comment: It might be best to raise this as a new question as it seems remote from the original question which was really about how SMBus/I2C works.